# AtomicLong operations

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, atomic-long

I need to perform the following operation:

```
// average, total, elapsed are Long's

average = ( ( total * average ) + elapsed ) / (++total);
```

But I want to use `AtomicLong`

This is what I'm trying but I don't quite get if it is correct:

```
 average.set( (( total.get() * average.get() ) + elapsed) / total.getAndIncrement() );
```

How can I tell if this is correct?

Comment: What you are doing is `... / (total++)`.  Is that what you want?  i.e. you are incrementing the `AtomicLong` but not `total` in your example operation.

Comment: Oh yes, total++ that's what I want.. mmhh I think I need ++total actually.

Comment: Then you want `total.incrementAndGet()`.

Comment: In such case, aren't you supposed to do this in a synchronized block?

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you are using AtomicLong because these numbers are being accessed concurrently.  Since you have two numbers involved and you are using both a get and incrementAndGet in the same statement, I don't think AtomicLong is the right choice.

I have found AtomicXXX to be very helpful in many situations.  But here, I think you need to do it the hard way.  Make your numbers simple "long" private variables, create a guard object, then make sure to synchronize on the guard object any time you access the numbers.

I think that is the only way you can be certain that these operations are truly atomic.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly note that on some platforms `AtomicLong` is implemented with a lock, so you may see a significant variation in performance.

You appear to be attempting to update two variables at once. Although many modern processors support that, the Java library does not. The version with a lock is trivial, so I'll elide that. You may also want to calculate the average on the get, and just keep a running sum and total, but I'll ignore that for the moment.

The most literal implementation would be using an `AtomicReference` to an immutable value. Note this is going to cause an allocation, so may have great performance, particularly under low contention.

```
final class Average { // Find a better name...
    private final long average;
    private final long total;
    public Average(long average, long total) {
        this.average = average
        this.total = total;
    }
    public long average() {
        return average;
    }
    public long total() {
        return total;
    }
}
...
private final AtomicReference<Average> averageRef = new AtomicReference<>();
private void elapsed(final long elapsed) {
    Average prev;
    Average next;
    do {
        prev = average.get();
        next = new Average(
            ((prev.total() * prev.average()) + elapsed ) / (prev.total() + 1),
            prev.total() + 1
        );
    } while (!average.compareAndSet(prev, next));
}
```

Possibly a better solution is to keep a thread local (preferably not `ThreadLocal` but an instance you've given to a particular thread to mutate). That can very quickly be locked and unlocked, because it'll be from the same thread. A thread infrequently requiring an average can then lock and read/read current values from all threads.

```
class Average { // Choose better name
    private long sum;
    private long total;
    public synchronized void elapsed(final long elapsed) {
         sum += elapsed;
         ++total;
    }
    public static long average(Iterable<Average> averages) {
        long sum = 0;
        long total = 0;
        for (Average average : averages) {
            synchronized (average) {
                sum += averages.sum;
                total += average.total;
            }
        }
        return total==0 ? 0 : (sum/total);
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: Not checked or tested or compiled.)

Comment: I'm also trying to know how many concurrent users do I have with: `simultaneous.set(simultaneous.incrementAndGet()); hanlde(newThreadEtc); simultaneous.set(simultaneous.decrementAndGet());`  Would that work or should I go the long path too?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that these calculations are going to be called by multiple threads concurrently.  I initially did not take that into effect.

If you want to use the `AtomicLong` to do the pre-increment calculation, then you should do something like:

```
long value = total.getAndIncrement();
average.set((value * average.get()) + elapsed) / (value + 1));
```

This *still* has race conditions however since the average could be updated by someone else between the `average.get()` and the `average.set()` call which would not be taken into effect in the update.

To be completely sure, you need to (as @user1657364 mentioned in their answer) lock around a guard object.

Answer (score 0):

In your assignment total might be different in the first total and total++. You need to synchronize the whole operation.